# Hide header and entire column when the value is equal to null. Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I've tried to google how to solve this problem.
But most of it was not related to this.

This program is to get input from user, which is in checkbox format, it will read all the content in text file and display it in table format on website.

> **QUESTION**

- Any possible command that the column only will be display if the column has value??

**Note : If you understand and saw this problem before be please to post the link here.**

**THIS IS MY TEXT FILE**

> ```
>  `delay_
>   775435
>   id 7754764
>   delay_
>   456345
>   id 64564
>   delay_
>   4567867867868
>   id 3453454
>   delay_
>   567867`
> ```
>
> **views.py**

```
tokens = request.GET.getlist('token')
# ...
with open(path) as input_data:
for line in input_data:

            if 'visual' in tokens and line.startswith('id_'):
                prev_key = line.lstrip('id_').rstrip()
                data.update({prev_key: []})
                # you may want to continue to next line here - or not
                # continue

            if 'time' in tokens:
                if search_string in line and prev_key in data:
                    data[prev_key].append(next(input_data).rstrip())

                else:

                    if search_string in line:
                        prev_key = (next(input_data).rstrip())
                        data.update({prev_key:[]})


context = {'output': data,}
```

> **html table**

```
<div class="input-group" align="center" style=" left:10px; top:-110px; width:99%">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="success" >

                <tr>

                    <th class="success">
                        <b>Visual ID</b>
                    </th>

                    <th class="success">

                    <b>Time Delay Index Time</b>

                    </th>

                </tr>

                {% for key, values in output.items %}

                <tr class="warning">
                    <td rowspan={{ values|length|add:1 }}><b>{{ key }}</b></td>

                    {% for value in values %}

                    <tr class="warning">
                    <td ><b>{{value}}{{key1}}</b></td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

                    </tr>

                {% endfor %}

                </thead>
            </table>
    </div>
```

> **REFERENCE**

[image: if user didn't check anything]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the template wrap the `<th>` definition in if block:

```
{% if output.your_key %}
   <th class="success">
     <b>Whatever you want </b>
   </th>
   # and so on
{% endif %}
```

So if the key is present in your output, you'll create a corresponding header, if not, you won't.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail, thanks for your effort for answer it. But I'm confused on your suggestion.

Comment: ok i think i misunderstood (and whatever if the dict is empty it won't work whatever). You want to hide the header of the column that's it? I update the answer

Comment: output.your_key means, sorry yaaa I'm a bit confused to this statement

Comment: well imagine your dictionnary is ```values['a_key'] = a_value```. I'm just test testing if 'a_key' is actually in the dict's keys. But that's how you writte it in jinja template : {% if values.a_key %} is equivalent to ```if 'a_keys' in values.keys()``` in python. Hope it's clear

Comment: did that answer your question or still not?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However I have make some changes base on your answer given on my template. You can refer to here https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnKg4.png | But when I click both or one of the checkbox it will show nothing. Is there any I'm misunderstood?

Comment: do you have any values in your dict.key for the if to be true?